# How can I get rid of an "indirect" foreign key? Should I?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

Here's an example schema to illustrate what I'm talking about:

[image: sample database schema]

Let's say I'm storing information about some activities (seminars, trainings, whatever) that are being hosted in a certain set of locations, identified by type (hackerspace, swimming pool, etc) and city. Each activity happens at all of the locations of a suitable type **at once** (e.g. any programming seminar happens at all of the hackerspaces at once), so any person may choose to attend an activity in any of the suitable locations. Therefore, any activity is associated only with some location type, while an attendance record is associated with some activity (and therefore implicitly with some location type) and the city where this particular user attended the activity.

The most common query in the system by far is generating a report of all activities attended by a given person.

Am I right in feeling that this is ugly? Should I try to redesign this, and if so, how?

P.S. I'd rather not reveal the actual data I'm storing in a database where I had to employ a similar design, so I hope that this analogy makes some sense.

Comment: locations is missing a primary key. (and the rest comes naturally)

Comment: @wildplasser the pair of (Type, City) is a primary key for Locations.

Comment: What if a location has more than one type? (hackerspace+swimmingpool+billiards)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need a `LocationTypes` table with a list of location types.  Then, `Location` can have a foreign key relationship to `LocationTypes`.

But, I don't like assuming that the set of locations doesn't change over time. So that is overly simplistic.  So, I would have another entity of something like `LocationSets`, which would list the locations for a given activity over time.  The `LocationSets` would contain the "type" which can be used.  The locations associated with a location set would be in another table, a junction table connecting the location sets and the locations.

Then `Activities` would have a `LocationSetId`.  And `Attendance` would have a `LocationId`.  You might want to enforce that at any given time, the `Attendance` location is consistent with the locations in the `Activity`'s `LocationSets`.  This could be done at the application layer, through a trigger in the database, or through mechanism such as a function-based constraint (if your database supports those).

Comment: *Sigh* It seems like my analogy is falling apart (that's completely my fault, though).
In my case, neither Locations nor Activities ever change at all, and, for each LocationType, there only exist a few Locations. Furthermore, the difference between multiple Locations with the same LocationType is very, very minor.